# Exporting HTML Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, html-table

How can I export an HTML table in my page as PDF and/or XLS? (preferably using JS (+jquery))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CSV format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) that is readable for MS Excel and OO Calc. 'Tis just an easiest way.

If you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can use [CSV Plugin](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php).

Comment: You can't export to pdf exactly from js. You can send CVS to php-script that can generate pdf - http://www.php.net/pdf